# jQuery AJAX JSON data not sending

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have the below code running to send data as a JSON object

```
var jdata = JSON.stringify(grid.serialize());
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'print.php',
    'data': jdata, //assuming you have the JSON library linked.
    'contentType': "application/json",
    'success': function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    'error': function (x, y, z) {
        alert(x.responseText);
        // x.responseText should have what's wrong
    }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(grid.serialize()));
```

Currenty the alert after the ajax function prints

> [{"id":"1","col":"1","row":"1","size_y":"1","size_x":"1"},{"id":"2","col":"2","row":"1","size_y":"1","size_x":"1"}]

On the receiving page I am using `<?php print_r($_POST) ?>` to see what the page is being sent and it keeps outputting

```
Array
(
)
```

I must be missing something simple but have been unable to figure out what. Maybe a fresh set of eyes will see a simple mistake I have made.

Comment: Just a quick guess... I think you must write post in lowercase. Otherwise... did you try with `$.post`?

Comment: Are you posting `[{"id":"1","col":"1","row":"1","size_y":"1","size_x":"1"},{"id":"2","col":"2","row":"1","size_y":"1","size_x":"1"}]` as is?

Comment: it doesn't matter if post in uppercase.

Comment: Launch Fiddler, http://fiddler2.com, or a similar tool to examine your form Post.

Comment: @Bimal: The problem here has nothing to do with cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$_POST` is only populated if you send the data encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. So, just assign the JSON string to a key (jQuery takes care of encoding it properly):

```
'data': {data: jdata}
```

and remove the `'contentType': "application/json"` part.

Then you get the data in PHP with:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

---

Alternatively, get the raw body of the request in PHP and process it: [How to retrieve Request Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9597052/218196)

Comment: I tried this method and it passes the json array but backsashes a of the double quotes

Comment: Then you should probably disable magic quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642901/php-5-3-automatically-escapes-get-post-from-form-strings

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending JSON to the server, on the back-end grab your JSON using:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

It won't be in the $_POST super global.